# Adding date when plotting seasons ggplot2

Tags: r

I want to plot time series for several years, but only for the summer months. My problem is when I try to add the date into the X-axis. Let's say that my data has the following structure:

```
      day       date    value      Region variable Data
       1    1998-06-01 72.69090      IP       O3  OBS
       2    1998-06-02 86.09606      IP       O3  OBS
       3    1998-06-03 93.50078      IP       O3  OBS
       4    1998-06-04 96.41037      IP       O3  OBS
        .........................................
      1194  2010-08-29  97.36273     IP       O3  OBS
      1195  2010-08-30 100.09310     IP       O3  OBS
      1196  2010-08-31  98.55973     IP       O3  OBS
```

and I convert dat$date to Date

I did my plot:

```
m <- ggplot(dat, aes(day, value)) + 
       geom_line(aes(color=Data),size=0.3,na.rm=TRUE)
```

In that case my plot looks like:
[image]

If I use dat$date instead as:

```
m <- ggplot(dat, aes(date, value)) +
       geom_line(aes(color=Data),size=0.3,na.rm=TRUE) +
       scale_x_date(date_breaks ="1 year",labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

Then I would have:
[image]

So, how can I add the date but getting a plot similar to the first one? 
I guess that it is because I'm only plotting 3-months, but I'd like to have a continuous. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. You should provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an x-axis with custom breaks, since a date or continuous axis will not skip months. First you make a factor of the days you want to plot, than construct a custom break axis.

```
set.seed(314)
dat <- data.frame(value = rnorm(1000, mean = 90, sd = 20),
                 day = as.Date('2017-01-01')+1:1000)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

dat.p <- dat[month(dat$day) %in% c(6,7,8),]

# plot with a date axis
ggplot(dat.p, aes(day, value)) + geom_line(size=0.3,na.rm=TRUE)

dat.p$x <- factor(dat.p$day)

dat.b <-  dat.p[mday(dat.p$day)==1,]

#plot with a custom axis

ggplot(dat.p, aes(x = x, y = value, group = 1)) + geom_line(size=0.3,na.rm=TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = dat.b$x, labels = dat.b$day)
```